# In Android Studio, the font has changed unexpectedly. How can I set it back to the normal font?

Tags: android-studio

I have typed something wrong, but I have no idea. The font has changed and it is causing an error. I also have restarted the program, and I have tried to change the settings, but it didn't work. Android Studio does not come back to the previous state where it was working.

This is how it looks like now:

[image: unexpected font change]

How can I get the font back to normal?

Answer (score 0):

**OUTSIDE** Android Studio, at the bottom-right corner of your screen, in the windows taskbar, verify that your Language and Keyboard settings haven't changed and are the expected, whatever language you are using normally.

If not, change them back to your normal language and keyboard:

[image]